# Abstract Algebra Benedict Gross

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently watching Harvard's Benedict Gross' lectures on Abstract Algebra available for free on internet. However, I don't have access to Artin's Book. Is there any way that I could find problem sets that go along with the course. I would like to follow the weekly/day to day problem pattern only if possible.
Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem sets are available under the [Gross' lecture site](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra). You can find Artin's book in every mathematical library, if you have access to it. Otherwise in an Internet shop like Amazon, since there is no legal e-book available.